# Reorder associated records with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I would like to save the order of the associated records, but ActiveRecord is automatically sorting them (I'm assuming so that it can search through the list faster later). I would like to save the order differently though. Currently I have something that looks like this:

```
m = Model.find 1
m.other_models_ids
irb> [1, 2, 3] 
m.other_models_ids = m.other_models_ids.shuffle
irb> [2, 1, 3]
m.save
m.other_models_ids
irb> [1, 2, 3]
```

I would like the order to be saved as [2, 1, 3]. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of sorting and saving them, why don't you sort while querying from the model?

Comment: Or you can have a position column in the other_model, update the position values while shuffling and scope that model in such a way that the query is based on the position column.

Answer (score 0):

The associated records are referred to as *collection* for a reason - they are not ordered. This in turn is due to the fact that they are based on SQL which does not provide a mechanism for establishing/preserving an order aside from utilizing column values for that purpose.

Assuming you can't rely on the order of the `id` value itself and that an individual "other_model" record can be associated with multiple "main" model records, you'll need to establish a separate table to contain both an "order" column and ids for each of the main/other records. You can then use a `has_many through:` relationship to that table.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do is not possible.

But what you are trying to do is possible with some tweaks.

Add a column named `position` to the `other_model` table

```
add_column :other_model, :position, :integer
```

And in your console

```
m = Model.find 1
m.other_models.shuffle.each_with_index do |val,index| 
  val.position = index + 1
  val.save!
end

m.reload
m.other_models.order(:position).select(:id).map(&:id)
```

This would produce the result you expect